# Copying some entries from one column to another with QGIS field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, syntax

I have some rows in the AttributeTable where I want to copy some entries from one column to another. I thought that the best way to do this was in the field calculator and use a `CASE WHEN` expression followed by `IN` (and the references I want to update) but I'm not sure where to go next? I thought I'd use `THEN` to select column I want the information from but it doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what are you asking but, since you are dealing with expressions, you may use an `if` statement from the Field Calculator:

```py
if(condition, result_when_true, result_when_false)
```

For example, assuming you have this Attribute Table:

[image]

and that you want to copy all the values from the `"numbers"` field to the `"newfield"` field which are equals to 5, you may use this expression:

```py
 if("numbers"=5, "numbers", NULL)
```

and you will have this result:

[image]

The code above is obviously an example: if you edit your question by adding more information about your issue, I may give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you, yes that's nearly along the right lines of what I meant, assume I have another column, call it 'newfield2' some rows have NULL, some have entries, i want to copy those rows which have entries in 'newfield2' to 'newfield' (hence why i thought best to use an IN function to select those 'numbers' where 'newfield' needs an update from another column)

Comment: Essentially, I had a dataset in a csv with data i wanted to update into my shapefile and its dbf, so I did a table join and those columns from the csv are at the end of my attribute table, many rows have a null value but some rows have data with which i wish to transfer to their corresponding column, but I wouldn't want the NULL values to overwrite data columns where there are values, for a more literal explanation, I have a list of sites which are tied to a floorspace value, I have a list of sites which need their floorspace values updating

Comment: @adamwilliams What about using  `if(  "numbers" ,"numbers",None)` as expression? In this way, you write the value stored in `"numbers"` if the `"numbers"` field stores an entry, otherwise it doesn't happen anything.

Answer (score 1):

If 'The references you want to update' means the target colum that gets the information when your test condition ist `true` then you must first select 'update existing field' and select the target field in field calculator (cp. screenshot below). It should be well noted, that the target field must have the correct field type, i.e. it is hardly possible to put `text` values in an `integer` field. This will result in `NULL` values as far as I see.

If you want to use `CASE WHEN [condition] THEN [result] ELSE [result] END` your expression should be something like

```
CASE WHEN "test_field" = 'value'
THEN
    "information_from_field"
ELSE
    "info_from_another_field"
END
```

Note that field names are in double quotes, and text values in single quotes.

[image]

Comment: Nearly there thanks :) the only issue im facing is the information i want is copying across but its overwriting fields with NULL where column im pointing the THEN to has NULL values

CASE WHEN  "REF" IN ('selected references to update')
THEN  "15-16 survey_B1a" 
ELSE
NULL
END

the update existing field is pointing to a column called B1a

Comment: Not shure if I'm getting you right, do you want to preserve values in the target column that must not be overwritten? Then you'll have to catch this in the WHEN condition somehow, sth. like CASE WHEN "cond_field" = 'value' AND "target_column" != 'protected_value' THEN "from_field". If you want to copy to more than one target field depending on a condition you're not going to succeed only with field calculator. In such cases I suggest graphical modeler to combine various field calculators or custom geoprocessing scripts.